# How to get max date value of returned result in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, max, limit

Can somebody tell me please how to get latest date value from current result set with regards to limit in Elasticsearch? It means not the max value of all item regardless of limit but only the one from limited result. 
I have this condition:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "publishDate": {"lte": "2018-10-10"}
        }    
    },
    "size": 20
}
```

Need max value from current limited result. Not other out of this range.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe sort them by publishDate and change the size to 1 ?

Comment: I would like to do it in one query if its possible.

Comment: Have you tried a sampler aggregation? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html

Comment: I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Just add sort to the query and take the first result

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [`max` metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "publishDate": {
        "lte": "2018-10-10"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "aggs": {
    "max_date": {                      <--- add this
      "max": {
        "field": "publishDate"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I got it, only from the 20 results that are showing, correct?

Comment: Yes thats the problem.